# vue3.0 + axios + Vite how to solve cors server problem?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, vuejs3, vite

On my vite.config.js file:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'
import path from 'node:path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    cors: true,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:8088",
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => {console.log(path); return path.replace(/^\/api/, '')}
      }
    }
  }
})
```

on my axios.js config:

```
import axios from "axios";


let config = {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8088/api',
    timeout: 1000,
    withCredentials: true
}

const instance = axios.create(config)

export default instance
```

then in my page send a request like this

```
 $axios.post('/user/login', {
        u_account: ruleForm.account,
        u_password: ruleForm.password
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.code === 200) {
            let token = response.data.token
            console.log('success!')
            window.localStorage.setItem('token', token)
        } else {
            console.log('failed');
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message)
    })
```

and then I got that cors request problem.

I've try to rewrite axios.js -> baseURL to 'api', but still no working, can somebody help?

Comment: "that cors request problem" — What CORS request problem? There are dozens of different CORS related error messages.

Comment: update the question and add information about the exact cors error if you can

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you're using a proxy, you don't set the base URL to the remote host. Just use `baseURL: "/api"`

Answer (score 1):

just update your Axios instance config to the following:

```js
let config = {
    baseURL: "/api",
    timeout: 1000,
    withCredentials: true
}
```

also, remove the cors property value false and make it an object as follows

```js
   cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
      preflightContinue: true,
      optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
      credentials:true,
    }
```

That should solve the issue assuming that your server URL is
http://localhost:8088